# How to fix "'StartDate' value of ... must follow dd.MM.yy format" with edfread on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signals, medical

I'm trying to import the EEG data from this public dataset with MATLAB: https://openneuro.org/datasets/ds002724/versions/1.0.1

In order to do so, I use the `edfread` function which comes with the Signal Processing Toolbox. I do it in the following way:

```
folder = '/Users/blancoarnau/ds002724-download/';

eeg_path = [folder,'sub-08/ses-3/eeg/sub-08_ses-3_task-run1_eeg.edf'];
eeg = edfread(eeg_path);
```

However, this error pops up:

```
Error using signal.internal.edf.validateEDF (line 31) 
'StartDate' value of
"/Users/blancoarnau/ds002724-download/sub-08/ses-3/eeg/sub-08_ses-3_task-run1_eeg.edf" must follow dd.MM.yy format.

Error in edfread (line 113)
signal.internal.edf.validateEDF(filename, fileInfo, version, startDate, startTime,...

Error in test (line 9)
eeg = edfread(eeg_path);
```

which suggests that the date format that the .edf file has is not in the dd.MM.yy format.

How can I fix this? Is there any tool that allows me to change this format? Or is there any other MATLAB function that allows me to import EEG files with other date formats?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community I have specified the problem in the question. I want to know how to have an .edf file in the dd.MM.yy format.

Answer (score 0):

as [Matlab help](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/edfread.html#mw_3164f11b-4869-426a-9f73-c1a35777962e) says :

> data = edfread(filename,Name,Value) reads the file into a timetable
> with additional options specified by one or more name-value pair
> arguments.

maybe you should use edfread with following name-value options:

```
...edfread(filename,'TimeOutputType','duration');
```

Comment: Hello @Hadi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, the same error pops up.